# sqlplus fails to start. wants *.msb files

Tags: oracle, sqlplus

Installed sqlplus from oracle downloads. Unpacked both files
instantclient-basic-linux.x64-12.1.0.1.0.zip
instantclient-sqlplus-linux.x64-12.1.0.1.0.zip 
sqlplus fails to start with this error:

Error 6 initializing SQL*Plus
 SP2-0667: Message file sp1.msb not found
 SP2-0750: You may need to set ORACLE_HOME to your Oracle software directory

I assume I don't have to install the whole oracle server for sql client to run. and basic-linux zip is deemed to be everything you need to run OCI apps which sqlplus is.

Where do I get these .msb files?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> You may need to set ORACLE_HOME to your Oracle software directory

You need to set ORACLE_HOME to wherever you've unzippd the files:

```
export ORACLE_HOME=/path/to/instantclient
```

You probably also want to add that to your PATH, and might need to add it to LD_LIBRARY_PATH. Which is actually all the [instructions tell you to do](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/features/instant-client/index.html).

Comment: thanks, only LD_LIBRARY_PATH was needed, just like the instructions you mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

ensure to have you ORACLE_HOME/sqlplus, ORACLE_HOME/sqlplus/mesg directories allowed for read and execute, and all the ORACLE_HOME/sqlplus/mesg/*.msb files readable too when trying to use sqlplus with a non oracle owner user.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone that is using 12C on up, and you are just setting up a DB for your desktop(not sure about servers). You do not need to have the oracle_home as an environmental variable for your account. If you created one, then just delete and see what happens. I have installed 12C and 19c oracle db, and I'm able to use sqlplus just fine. I did not do anything fancy with the install. I just selected a virtual user and basically clicked next for everything else.